# How do I use libphonenumber to find phone numbers?

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the [libphonenumber-csharp](https://github.com/twcclegg/libphonenumber-csharp) library and the FindNumbers feature. But I am unable to implement it properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();                    

var a = phoneUtil.findNumbers("this is my phone number: (805) 527-9975", null);
Console.WriteLine(a);

Console.Write(phoneUtil.findNumbers("8055279975", "US"));

public Iterable<PhoneNumberMatch> findNumbers(CharSequence text, String defaultRegion);
```

Comment: Well what is the problem?

Comment: *I am unable to implement it properly* is not a useful problem description. What specific problem are you having with the code you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code and I am getting this as the output: 
java.lang.Iterable`1[com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatch]
java.lang.Iterable`1[com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatch]

Are you getting the same result? looking into the issue now and I'll let you know if I figure it out.

**EDIT**

I was able to figure it out! 
The correct way to do it is like this:

```
string testString = "testing the ability to grab here: 345-365-567";
{
                PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
                PhoneNumber phoneNumber = phoneUtil.Parse(testString, "US");

//now from here you can do ahead and retrieve the number by calling upon phoneNumber.

     Console.WriteLine(phoneNumber.NationalNumber);
}
```

Comment: Usually this would belong as a comment under the original post rather than an answer

Comment: @Saddy My apologies! I will keep that in mind for next time :)

Comment: @Saddy, you can delete your answer and write a comment...

Comment: @VillageTech I was able to figure it out and planned on doing so. Deleting seemed silly, but all is good now! :)